# How do hadoop know your key type in streaming mode

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

After map and before reduce, there is a sort phase. In streaming mode, how does hadoop know what you key type is, and sort it.

For example

Input file format

```
1990    1
1991    4
1992    5
...
```

The result of map has keys 1990,1991,1992..., how hadoop sorts it? (numberic sort or alphabetical sort)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the StreamJob, the map output key/value pairs are specified as

```
idResolver.resolve(jobConf_.get("stream.map.output",
  IdentifierResolver.TEXT_ID));
jobConf_.setClass("stream.map.output.reader.class",
  idResolver.getOutputReaderClass(), OutputReader.class);
jobConf_.setMapOutputKeyClass(idResolver.getOutputKeyClass());
jobConf_.setMapOutputValueClass(idResolver.getOutputValueClass());
```

Unless, `stream.map.output` property is set to `rawbytes` or `typedbytes`, the map output key/value are set as Text.class in IdentifierResolver#resolve.

```
setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
```

In the Text.java, Comparator subclass extends WritableComparator and implements compare method which does compare in Lexicographic order (dictionary or alphabetical order).

Check the [StreamJob](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/tags/release-0.21.0/mapreduce/src/contrib/streaming/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/streaming/StreamJob.java), [IdentifierResolver](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/tags/release-0.21.0/mapreduce/src/contrib/streaming/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/streaming/io/IdentifierResolver.java) and [Text](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/tags/release-0.21.0/common/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/io/Text.java) classes.